# How to use RubyMine, Rails and Docker (Remote SDK)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubymine

Unfortunately I've troubles to set up a remote Docker sdk within RubyMine. My Ruby image and container based on that work flawlessly with my app, but somehow I can't configure RubyMine properly, so I can develop with this instance.

[image]

The main problem seems to be, that RubyMine doesn't detect the installed GEMs within the Docker container.

I've used the following `Dockerfile` to create the image:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000
```

And I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - "5432"
```

I tried to use the `docker-compose.yml` file to setup the remote SDK in RubyMine, but it just doesn't detect any installed gems.

[image]

Does someone have an idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although I'm not sure if this is what fixed it.

1. Figure out where the ruby home directory is in your container via `which ruby` or a similar command
2. Configure a new remote SDK of type "Docker"
3. Select the Docker server and the image used by the container of interest
4. Replace the "Ruby interpreter path" config's default `ruby` with the
   absolute path to the executable in your container
5. Run RubyMine's `bundle install` with the new remote SDK selected as
   the project SDK